# PHP Fatal Error when using constant()

Tags: php, constants

The manual entry for constant() says that if the constant is not defined the function should return NULL.  In the case of the code below, however, it gives a fatal error.

```
$constant = get_class($this) . '::' . $name;
$value = constant($constant);
```

If $name is valid, things work fine.  If it's not, however, I get a fatal error "Undefined class constant ..."  The manual says it should raise an E_WARNING error too but I'm not seeing this in the log file.

Comment: `$constant` is a variable, not a constant.

Comment: @bfavaretto: So? [read](http://php.net/constant)

Comment: Right, now I realize the dumbness of my comment.

Comment: @Kim Prince:  I am not getting a fatal error on my end.  Please include a SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) in your question, along with your PHP version.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I'm getting fatal here on php 5.3

Comment: See [bug 51791](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51791), the fatal error exists in versions 5.3.0–5.3.2 inclusive.

Comment: I'm using 5.3.2, so that explains it then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP setup *may* be setup to treat all errors as fatal errors.  If that is the case,  checking to see if the constant exists before you try to retrieve it will be a fix:

```
$constant = get_class($this) . '::' . $name;
$value = defined($constant) ? constant($constant) : null;
```

Comment: Nope, it's likely a version-dependent behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the constant is [defined](http://php.net/defined) first, and then throw an exception instead (or proceed with whatever flow you're following).

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens with PHP 8.
See [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php)

> A number of warnings have been converted into Error exceptions:
>
> - Attempting to access unqualified constants which are undefined. Previously, unqualified constant accesses resulted in a warning and were interpreted as strings.